# How can I fix this "package does not exist" error?

Tags: java

On OS X.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02-279-10M3065)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01-279, mixed mode)
```

Here's my whole project:

```
$ ll
total 1072
-rw-r--r--  1 ethan  ethan    1316 Oct 19 17:17 BlackberryDataExtractor.class
-rw-r--r--  1 ethan  ethan    1439 Oct 19 18:05 BlackberryDataExtractor.java
-rw-r--r--@ 1 ethan  ethan  537303 Apr 19  2010 sqljdbc4.jar
                                                    <-- MS SQL Server JDBC driver
```

Here's `BlackberryDataExtractor.java`. It doesn't really do anything yet. I'm just trying to get basic stuff working like DB connection:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc;

class BlackberryDataExtractor {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection con = BlackberryDataExtractor.getConnection();
  }

  public static final Connection getConnection()
  {
    Connection con = null;
    try
    {
      Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://[ etc... ]");
      String SQL = "SELECT uc.MailboxSMTPAddr AS email, sd.PhoneNumber AS phone_number"
        + "FROM dbo.UserConfig uc, dbo.SyncDeviceMgmtSummary sd"
        + "WHERE sd.UserConfigId = uc.Id";
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

      while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("email") + ", " + rs.getString("phone_number"));
      }
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();

    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
  }
}
```

It won't compile. Here's the error:

```
$ javac -cp "$CLASSPATH;*.jar" BlackberryDataExtractor.java
BlackberryDataExtractor.java:4: package com.microsoft.sqlserver does not exist
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc;
                              ^
BlackberryDataExtractor.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Statement
location: class BlackberryDataExtractor
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
      ^
BlackberryDataExtractor.java:24: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ResultSet
location: class BlackberryDataExtractor
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
      ^
3 errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`javac` does not understand wildcards like `*.jar`. You have to be explicit.

Try `javac -cp "$CLASSPATH;sqljdbc4.jar" ...`

Comment: Your import statement is incorrect anyway. You can't import an entire package unless you do `import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;`, unless there is actually a class named `jdbc` in the package `com.microsoft.sqlserver`.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot how to write Java (or suppressed it, rather). I fixed the import statement. Tried `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;` and then tried importing the classes individually. Neither works. javac still isn't finding the classes.

Comment: Are you on Windows or *nix? The path separator for the latter is `:` not `;` (as it is on Windows). i.e. `-cp "$CLASSPATH:sqljdbc4.jar`. Also I just realized I quoted the jar as "sqljdbc4.jar.jar" in my first answer.

Comment: Given that the error output he pasted included a "$" prompt, I'm guessing he's on a *nix variant.

Comment: Java 6 *does* understand wildcards. The problem is that ':' should be used instead of ';' as a path separator on Mac OS X.

Comment: Yes it appears that it was the ":" and the incorrect import statements.

Answer (score 1):

Does speciffing the jar file directly instead of with a glob "*.jar" work?

```
javac -cp "$CLASSPATH;sqljdbc4.jar" BlackberryDataExtractor.java
```

It also looks like you're missing a few java.sql.   imports.  (ResultSet and Statement)

Comment: Does the jar actually contain the classes you are importing?  jar tf sqljdbc4.jar   should list the com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc class files if so.

Comment: Yes, it definitely contains those classes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I was writing and executing a program in Eclipse everything worked correctly, but when I was executing it in terminal (Ubuntu) then I got an error "package com.microsoft.sqlserver does not exist". I'm not sure if it is a good solution but I exported my project to jar file and then ran `java -jar "filename".jar.` and then everything was ok.