# ClassNotFoundException for com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

This is an issue that has come up [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974114/how-can-i-fix-this-package-does-not-exist-error) on SO, and I'm sure seasoned Java devs are tired of telling newbies howto set the classpath. That said, I've tried setting the classpath via environment variable and with the -cp option, with no success.

I'm using the sample applications that are bundled with the SQLServer JDBC driver. I'm running Ubuntu 14.10. I compile the app on the command line:

```
javac -cp .:/path/to/sqljdbc42.jar connectURL.java
```

and the run it:

```
java connectURL
```

which gets me the familiar `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at connectURL.main(connectURL.java:42)
```

I haven't modified the sample class file, but I'm including it here for completeness:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class connectURL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a variable for the connection string.
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
            "databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;";

        // Declare the JDBC objects.
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

            try {
                // Establish the connection.
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

                    // Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data.
                    String SQL = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Person.Contact";
                    stmt = con.createStatement();
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

                    // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        System.out.println(rs.getString(4) + " " + rs.getString(6));
                    }
            }

        // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
                if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
                if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

The path to the SQL JDBC .jar is definitely correct. If I add `import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;` to the class file I don't get any complaints when compiling, but still get the `ClassNotFoundException` at runtime.

I've read elsewhere that newer versions of the JDBC don't need you to load drivers via `Class.forName`, but if I remove that line then I get, predictably, `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found`.

What am I doing wrong? I'm sure the .jar is being loaded and the class is being found, because if I try e.g. `import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SomeNonExistentClass;` I get:

`connectURL.java:2: error: cannot find symbol`

My Java details:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.10.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're halfway there. You include the JDBC JAR on your classpath when you compile, but you also need to include it on your classpath when you execute it as well:

```
java -cp .:/path/to/sqljdbc42.jar connectURL
```

Comment: Oh good grief, what a fool I am! Thank you. Accepting in 8 mins when SO lets me :) (and thank you for being gentle)